# Connection between moments and characteristic function

Tags: probability

I am getting familiar with some basics ins probability theory and I have a question concerning moment-generating functions and characteristic functions. The following is cited from Wikipedia:

> A key problem with moment-generating functions is that moments and the
>   moment-generating function may not exist, as the integrals need not
>   converge absolutely. By contrast, the characteristic function always
>   exists (because it is the integral of a bounded function on a space of
>   finite measure), and thus may be used instead

Is there a connection between the following two facts?

- the characteristic function is (real) analytic
- moments of all order exist

Furthermore I have one question in mind somehow:

- If a distribution has a characteristic function that is analytic, is the distribution then moment-determinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a connection between those two facts.

If the characteristic function $\phi(t)$ for a distribution $F(x)$ exists and is analytic in some neighborhood of the origin, all moments exist and the characteristic function has the expansion:

$$\phi(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{i^km_k}{k!}z^k$$

for $|z|<\rho$ where $\rho$ is the radius of convergence of the series.

See *On Analytic Characteristic Functions*, Lukacs and Szasz 1953.