# Laplacian transform, moments or characteristic function of a random variable

Tags: probability, laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions, characteristic-functions

Let $Z$ be a real random variable, we define the Laplace transform of $Z$ as follows:
$L_Z(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda Z})$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

> What links can be shown between the Laplace transform of $Z$ and the moments of $Z$

If $Z$ has a CDF $F_Z$. The moment generating function (mgf) of $Z$ (or $F_Z$ ), denoted by $M_Z(t)$, is $M_Z(t)=\mathrm{E}(e^{t Z})$. Thus $L_Z(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda Z}) = M_Z(\lambda)$.

> What links can be shown between the Laplace transform of $Z$ and the characteristic function of $Z$

We define the characteristic function of $Z$ as $\varphi_X(t)=\mathrm{E}(e^{i t X})$. Thus $L_Z(i\lambda) = \mathbb{E}(e^{i\lambda Z}) = \varphi_X(\lambda)$.

Is this correct or do I have to change something?

Comment: It is all in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function). You may want to say that when $L_Z(\lambda)$ exists for real $\lambda$ the characteristic function $L_Z(i\lambda)$ does not necessarily exist. It does however when $L_Z$ is analytic. See also [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891541/connection-between-moments-and-characteristic-function?rq=1).